# Search for a deleted table's reference id in all tables, rows and columns of a DB

Tags: mysql, database, reference, foreign-keys

I had created a table in my DB and then deleted whole table. but now I got error of Foreign Key constraint of that table id. And due to it I am unable to update any other thing for my app in local.

I am having 400+ tables in my database with thousands of records.

How could I find that deleted table's reference id in my all current tables?

Comment: That would not have been possible unless you had set foreign_key_checks = false..If you did delete all the rows from the table(as opposed to dropping the table) I suggest you recover that table from backup and proceed with caution.

Comment: Yes I had set foreign_key_checks = false before deleting that table and again set it to true after deletion. then also this issue arises.

Comment: That's why the issue arose - as I said try to recover from backup.

Comment: I had recovered the dropped tables from the database backup and restored them. Thanks for your suggestion. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to find all the referenced tables for the deleted table in the system database `information_schema`:

```sql
SELECT 
  kcu.TABLE_NAME, kcu.CONSTRAINT_NAME, kcu.COLUMN_NAME, 
  kcu.REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME, kcu.REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME
FROM information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE kcu
WHERE kcu.REFERENCED_TABLE_SCHEMA = 'YourDatabaseName' AND 
      kcu.REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME = 'YourDeletedTableName'
```

Comment: user14717238, Thanks for you reply and guiding me. But do I have to run this query for all 400+ tables each time by replacing Table names and Column(s) names? it looks very lenghty and time consuming process...

Comment: user14717238, Thanks you very much for this. You saved my time and it worked like a charm. I got the Reference Constraint. Thanks again for this quick solution. :)

Comment: @@user14717238 Is there a way to get all the id of that deleted table from all referenced tables?

Comment: You can build a SQL query for each referenced table to get the values of the referenced column. Add this expression to the query in the `SELECT` clause and see the result - `CONCAT('SELECT ', kcu.COLUMN_NAME, ' FROM ', kcu.TABLE_NAME, ';') AS sql_select`

Comment: And see how to execute prepared queries from dynamically created string variables, if the number of such queries is really large. - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html

Comment: I got the referenced table id which got deleted in my system database. Thanks @id'7238 :)

Answer (score 0):

You can search on the whole schema(DB) from mysql workbench for the referenced column name from there you will be able to find all the references

Comment: Can you please provide any reference? as I had google it and didn't found what I want.